# Python list numbers with selection

Tags: python

I'm new to programming and currently learning python with reference book *Python Programming Fundamentals*. Here is one of the question I am dealing with:

1: Request user to input a list of numbers.

2: Then output those numbers which is in between 0 and 100.

Following is my code:

```
s = input("Please enter a list of numbers:") # request user to input a list of numbers
lst = s.split()                              # Now lst is a list of strings.
    output = []                              # Here is the beginning of the accumulator pattern

for e in lst:
    if float(e) > 0 and float(e) < 100 :     # inbetween 0 and 100
        output = output.append(float(e))
    else:
        output = output

print("The number between 0 and 100 are ", output)
```

And the error is:

```
File "c:\Users\HKGGAIT001\Desktop\1.py", line 7, in <module>
  output = output.append(float(e))
builtins.AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append
```

Comment: `append` is an inplace operation and it returns `None`. So, you are making `output` to `None`. So, in the next iteration you are trying to append to a `NoneType` object. Thats why that error is thrown

Comment: Are you using Python2 or Python3? It's important because `input` works differently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you are using Python3 (because it's unlikely the .split() would be successful in Python2)

This part is ok

```
s = input("Please enter a list of numbers:") # request user to input a list of numbers
lst = s.split()                              # Now lst is a list of strings.
output = []                              # Here is the beginning of the accumulator pattern
```

You can write the loop like this

```
for e in lst:
    if 0 < float(e) < 100 :     # inbetween 0 and 100
         output.append(float(e))
```

Notice that there are two comparisons. There is an implicit `and`. This is called a [chained comparison](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/expressions.html#not-in)

This pattern can be reduced down to a single line using a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20comprehension#list-comprehensions)

```
output = [float(e) for e in lst if 0 < float(e) < 100]
```

But now we need to use `float(e)` twice

We can use another [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20comprehension#list-comprehensions) to make `lst` already a list of `float`

```
s = input("Please enter a list of numbers:") # request user to input a list of numbers
lst = [float(e) for e in s.split()]          # Now lst is a list of floats.
output = [e for e in lst if 0 < e < 100]
```

Since we only need to iterate `lst` once, a tiny change makes it a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=generator%20expression#generator-expressions). So your final program could be

```
s = input("Please enter a list of numbers:") # request user to input a list of numbers
lst = (float(e) for e in s.split())          # Now lst is a generator of floats.
output = [e for e in lst if 0 < e < 100]
print("The number between 0 and 100 are ", output)
```

Comment: Hi. Many thanks for your gentle help!<br/>
The procedure is very clear.

Comment: Indeed is there any good reference book you recommended me to read?

Answer (score 1):

Your current code has a couple of issues, assuming you're in `Python 2.x`.

1. Using `input` causes Python to try to evaluate the user input, which will cause problems because you want them to input a list of numbers. `raw_input` will just give you what the user input without trying to parse it.
2. `list.append` is in-place, which means that the side effect of the function call will simply perform the append on the object it is called on, instead of returning a new object.

Try this:

```
s = raw_input("Please enter a list of numbers: ") 
lst = s.split()
output = []

for e in lst:
    if float(e) > 0 and float(e) < 100 :     # inbetween 0 and 100
         output.append(float(e))

print("The number between 0 and 100 are ", output)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
     s = str(input("Please enter a list of numbers:")) 
     lst = s.split()                              
    output = [] 
    for e in lst:
          if float(e) > 0 and float(e) < 100 :    
    output.append(float(e))
    print("The number between 0 and 100 are ", output)
    else:
    print("The number less than 0 or greter than 100 ", e)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = input("Please enter a list of numbers:")
output = [each for each in s if each > 0.0 and each < 100.0]
print("The number between 0 and 100 are ", output)
```